# How to convert DATE into DATETIME

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle 18 edition and I'm trying to convert `DATE` into `DATETIME` data type but I keep getting an error message.

This is my code:

```
ALTER TABLE APPOINTMENT_ldr
MODIFY ApptDateTime DATETIME;
```

> ERROR at line 2:
> ORA-22858: invalid alteration of datatype

Comment: `Date` is a valid datetime datatype in Oracle, but I don't think `datetime` is. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-A3C0D836-BADB-44E5-A5D4-265BA5968483 Despite its name, `Date` can store times if that's your concern.

Comment: So I should be able to store the date and time within the date datatype?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the documentation I linked, `Date` is a valid datetime datatype. It can store time.

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not have a `DATETIME` data type.

The `DATE` data-type has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components so you want to use that.

---

The user interface you are using may choose not to show the time component but it is always there.

If you are using SQL/Plus or SQL Developer then you can change how a `DATE` is displayed in your current session using:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';`
```

If you want to display a `DATE` using a specific format then use `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(date_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
FROM   table_name;
```